# Almacenar un texto en un Arraylist?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, text

Necesito saber la sintaxis o funciones para almacenar un texto por ejemplo (El perro iba caminando caminando por la calle) ese texto en un arraylist, y que cada palabra de ese texto ocupe un espacio en ese arraylist, para después comparar el arraylist consigo misma y saber cuantas palabras se repiten en ese texto. (El texto puede ser ingresado por el usuario)

Comment: Añade por favor el código que has desarrollado para solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, agrega lo que has intentado y modifica tu pregunta en base a [ask] para que puedas obtener la ayuda deseada en el sitio, 
Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

A continuación te propongo un código que te permite leer por consola una cadena y luego convertirla a ArrayList

`BufferedReader` - Te permite crear un buffer para realizar la lectura de datos
`reader.readline().split(" ")` - Realiza la lectura de la línea y la parte por espacios, creando así un arreglo

Finalmente con el foreach recorremos el ArrayList para imprimir cada una de las palabras leidas

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    ArrayList<String> palabras = new ArrayList<>(); 

    String cadena[] = reader.readLine().split(" ");
    palabras.addAll(Arrays.asList(cadena));

    // Imprimimos cada valor en el ArrayList como prueba
    for (String palabra : palabras) {
      System.out.println(palabra);
    }
  }
}
```